# Multiple XML elements to the same class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'd like to do the following with JAXB, but don't know, how to. I'll show you some code, first, and after that, the details.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class RootClass {    
    @XmlElementWrapper("foos")
    // ?? - I do not want to list here all my xml element 
    // types with @XmlElements({...})
    private List<Foo> fooList;    
}

public class Foo {    
    @XmlTransient
    // how to map the element's type (based on the xml element)
    // into this attribute?
    private FooType type;

    @XmlElement(name = "something", type = Something.class)
    private Something something;    
}

public class Baz extends Foo {
    @XmlElement(name = "somethingMore", type = SomethingMore.class)
    private SomethingMore more;
}

public enum FooType {
    BAR,
    QUX
}
```

And the XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="mynamespace"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="myschemalocation">

    <foos>
        <bar>
            <something ... />
        </bar>
        <qux>
            <something ... />
        </qux>
        <baz>
            <something ... />
            <somethingMore ... />
        </baz>
    </foos>
</root>
```

So, I have the classes above, and the XML structure. Almost all my Foo-s are almost the same, but they differ in the FooType attribute. But some of my Foo-s are very-very different: I'd like to create a new class (which extends the original Foo) for them. In this example this class called `Baz`.

Is this possible, with JAXB, to unmarshall this structure? At the end of this example, I'd like to get a RootClass object, which has a list with 3 elements:

- one Foo object, which's type is `BAR`
- one Foo object, which's type is `QUX`
- and one `Baz` object.

Is it possible, with JAXB somehow? I've searched for hours. I've tried to create an 'ObjectFactory' with the `@XmlRegistry` and `@XmlElementDecl` annotations, but I'm not sure, how to do this.

Comment: Basically it is possible, but you'll have to define somewhere, that your `<foos>` contains a sequence of `<bar> <qux> <baz>`, with their types (Foo and Baz). XML parsers will not accept unknown element names if you want these elements to be unmarshalled.

Comment: Okay, I have the correct .xsd for the XML structure. My IDE validates it, and says it's OK. But that didn't solved my problem.

Comment: So what is the XML Schema? Use xjc to generate the Java classes - this should do it.

Comment: The xjc will generate different classes for `bar` and `qux`, isn't it? I'd want to map thoose to the same Java class, where one attribute shows the type.

Comment: No, it won't. - If you have specified *exactly* three elements, there won't be a List, you'll have three fields in the class for `<foos>`. And I don't see why you'd need `<foos>` if you'd want to have the foo/qux/bar in the root element.

Comment: Yeah, but I want a list.

Comment: Well, I thought so. Examples are misleading - that's why an XML Schema is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XML schema according to one of the two following possibilities. The difference arises from the requirement of having a mixed list in contrast to a sequence of three homogeneous lists.

Mixed list first:

```
<xsd:element name="root" type="RootType"/>
<xsd:complexType name="RootType">
  <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xsd:element name="bar" type="FooType"/>
    <xsd:element name="qux" type="FooType"/>
    <xsd:element name="baz" type="BazType"/>
  </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
```

This will result (in class RootType) in a

```
protected List<JAXBElement<? extends FooType>> barOrQuxOrBaz;
```

where the JAXBElement lets you extract a Qname identifying the element (basically the bar/qux/baz distinction) and the POJO of the unmarshalled element.

The other variant isn't so messy w.r.t. the resulting API:

```
<xsd:element name="root" type="RootType"/>
<xsd:complexType name="RootType">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="bar" type="FooType"
                 minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xsd:element name="qux"  maxOccurs="unbounded" type="FooType"
                 minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>            
    <xsd:element name="baz" type="BazType"
                 minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>     
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

This will give you the very simple

```
protected List<FooType> bar;
protected List<FooType> qux;
protected List<BazType> baz;
```